# making a picture profile for Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, presets, camera-profiles

I want to make a picture profile to apply a solid color adjustment layer to a base edit. I have a look I want to make for lightroom profile. I am in camera raw and made the basic adjustments. not changing temp or exposure. but there is a look I like on my images where I take the edited photo into photoshop and add a solid color adjust layer. I'd like that layer baked into the profile I want to make for lightroom so that I can create my presets. would you sugguest I add this Solid Color Adjustment layer first on a smart object then re-open camera raw, make the adjustments and save that as a profile, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ACR profile cannot include an adjustment layer from photoshop. It can only include edits made in ACR.

IMO your best option is to add the color with a mask.